# Jenkins can't reach Sonarqube

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am currently trying to get my Jenkins/Sonar integration to work.

Here is what I have:
Jenkins is working
Sonarqube is working (reachable from webinterface)
Ports are open

However!
I tried all possible settings, Jenkins insists that Sonarqube is Localhost:9000, no matter what I tell it (and even if, this should work too). This leads to following:

[image]

and ultimately lets the build fail.
What could I try to rectify this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`localhost:9000` is the default sonar qube url, regarding [the official documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven).  You'll have to set the correct url in your `pom.xml` (assuming you're ussing Maven, which seems to be the case).

if you set the `sonar.host.url` property in your `pom.xml` or `settings.xml` with your correct sonar qube url (ie: 192.168.0.9 for example), it should work as expected

```
       <properties>
            <!-- Optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
            <sonar.host.url>
              http://myserver:9000
            </sonar.host.url>
        </properties>
```

Comment: Right, I didn't know there was an option in pom.xml, let me try that.

Comment: It seems to still not work. Jenkins simply can't reach the Sonarqube server even though it's literally on the same machine.

Comment: What is the adress of your sonar qube instance ?

Comment: Jenkins: 10.0.0.8:8080
Solar: 10.0.0.8:9000

Funniest part, I just confirmed that the port is open and does not refuse connection from my local PC (Connected via VPN to the server network)

Comment: then set the url to 10.0.0.8:9000. Check if the route is open (even it should be) from jenkins (and not from your computer). `telnet 10.0.0.8 9000` from jenkins should work (ie: not getting a connection refused error)

Comment: I tried that, it works. Though, I used my VM (where Jenkins and Sonar are running) to do so. Is there are way to telnet somewhere using the Jenkins Webinterface á la PFSense, for example?

Comment: Nevermind. Your answer was correct, I was just looking in a completely wrong place.