# SonarQube Unable to reach Localhost

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I'm trying to build sonarqube via jenkins pipeline script, during the build i am getting error unable to reach localhost 9000.

```
15:30:58.225 ERROR: SonarQube server [http://localhost:9000] can not be reached
15:30:58.225 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:30:58.226 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
15:30:58.226 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:30:58.227 INFO: Total time: 0.603s
15:30:58.243 INFO: Final Memory: 3M/121M
15:30:58.245 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
15:30:58.246 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.ScannerException: Unable to execute SonarQube
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.lambda$createLauncher$0(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherFactory.createLauncher(IsolatedLauncherFactory.java:70)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doStart(EmbeddedScanner.java:185)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.start(EmbeddedScanner.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:73)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to get bootstrap index from server
    at 
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000
```

Note: I can able to access my localhost sonar 9000 in y browser, and also in above jenkins output there was one build point url like localhost:9000 also able to access from the jenkins logs, but at end of the line there was one line like unable to reach the host 127.0.0.1

```
vi /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 sonarqube
```

```
def label = "worker-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"

podTemplate(label: label, containers: [
        containerTemplate(name: 'nodejs', image: 'node:10-buster', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat'),
            containerTemplate(name: 'docker', image: 'docker:1.12.6', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true),
    containerTemplate(name: 'sonarqube', image: 'sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:latest', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true),
    containerTemplate(name: 'kubectl', image: 'lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl:v1.8.3', command: 'cat', ttyEnabled: true)

],
volumes: [
   hostPathVolume(mountPath: '/var/run/docker.sock', hostPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'),
]) {
  node(label) {
    def myRepo = checkout scm
    def gitCommit = myRepo.GIT_COMMIT
    def gitBranch = myRepo.GIT_BRANCH
    def shortGitCommit = "${gitCommit[0..10]}"
    def previousGitCommit = sh(script: "git rev-parse ${gitCommit}~", returnStdout: true)



    stage('sonar-scanner') {
     container('sonarqube') {
       sh "/opt/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner -X -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 -Dsonar.login=admin"
      }
  }


}

}
```

Comment: Is Jenkins executing the build in a docker container?

Comment: Yes i am using pod container template in pipeline script shall i update my script here ?

Comment: Hi Ale, Can you please help we are affecting entire project due to this issue

Comment: From within the container, the host is not reachable as localhost. Use the external DNS name (or ip) instead. Also, have you read this q/a: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38995148/jenkins-cant-reach-sonarqube?rq=1

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the quick response , where i have update IP address inside the /etc/hosts file like this 10.0.0.4 localhost

Comment: Just make sure you have local DNS server resolving "sonarqube" to 10.0.0.4 *or* use this address directly in your script (which will likely break at some time in the future).

Comment: Hi Alex, Your great you saved my life thanks lot for the quick response, now i resolved the issue based on your advice . i have update my jenkins script now sh "/opt/sonar-scanner/bin/sonar-scanner -X -Dsonar.host.url=http://10.0.0.4:9000

Comment: Fine, would be nice if you could accept my (now posted) answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your Jenkins is running the build in a docker container as mentioned in the comments, the solution is to use the IP address or a local DNS name to access sonarqube from within the build script, since localhost does not resolve to the host machine inside a docker container.